# Querying two tables in grails

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes in my grails project. the first one is user and second one is contact. the user has one to many relationship with the contact class, i.e one user has many contacts. the user class is like this

```
package contacts

class User {
    String name
    String email
    String password

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false)
        email(nullable: false,email: true,blank: false )
        password(nullable: false,size: 6..8,blank: false,password:true)
    }
    static hasMany = [contacts: Contact]

    String toString(){
        return name
    }
}
```

and the contact class is like this

```
package contacts

class Contact {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
    String phone
    String address
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {

        firstName(nullable: false)
        lastName(nullable: true)
        email(nullable: false)
        phone(nullable: true)
        address(nullable: true)
        dateCreated()
    }
       static belongsTo = [user: User]

}
```

when I compile this, it creates two tables named user and contact, the contact table has user_id as foreign key from user table which is called id in user table. Now I want retrieve all the contacts of some specific user. I am wondering how to do this. I have tried different approaches of dynamic querying but failed. Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: What are your different "approaches"?

Comment: The answer to your question is in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637961/1806218)

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have the User object, then it is as simple as:

```
def contacts = user.contacts
```

If a userId is being passed to some service to retrieve them you can do:

```
def getUserContacts(Long userId) {
  def user = User.load(userId)
  def contacts = Contact.findAllByUser(user)
}
```